# Ionic paypal id transaction

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, paypal

Good morning, I'm researching a lot but I still have not got what I want, I'm new to it all.
I'd like to know how I can get the transaction ID when making a payment via PayPal.
I did not find anything at https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/
Could anyone help me on how can I get the transaction id after payment?
My idea is to generate a QR Code after the payment, based on the data of the transaction made.
Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
this.payPal.init({
  PayPalEnvironmentProduction: ''
  PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'mySandbox',
}).then(() => {
  this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new PayPalConfiguration({
    acceptCreditCards: false,
    languageOrLocale: 'pt-BR',
    merchantName: (this.produto.nom_produto),
    merchantPrivacyPolicyURL: '',
    merchantUserAgreementURL: ''
  })).then(() => {
    let detail = new PayPalPaymentDetails('1.00', '0.00', '0.00');
    let payment = new PayPalPayment('1.00', 'BRL', 'Produto', 'Sale', detail);
    this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then((response) => {
      console.log('pagamento efetuado');
      this.createCode();
      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({ duration: 3000, position: 'bottom' });
      toast.setMessage('Pagamento efetuado com sucesso');
      toast.present();
    }, () => {
      console.log('erro ao renderizar o pagamento do paypal');
    })
  })
})
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully paid. You can fin bellow the id of transaction

```
this.payPal.init({
      PayPalEnvironmentProduction: ''
      PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'mySandbox',
    }).then(() => {
      this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new PayPalConfiguration({
        acceptCreditCards: false,
        languageOrLocale: 'pt-BR',
        merchantName: (this.produto.nom_produto),
        merchantPrivacyPolicyURL: '',
        merchantUserAgreementURL: ''
      })).then(() => {
        let detail = new PayPalPaymentDetails('1.00', '0.00', '0.00');
        let payment = new PayPalPayment('1.00', 'BRL', 'Produto', 'Sale', detail);
        this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then((response) => {
          console.log('pagamento efetuado');
          let transactionId = response.response.id;
          console.log('Your transaction id is ', transactionId);
          this.createCode();
          let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({ duration: 3000, position: 'bottom' });
          toast.setMessage('Pagamento efetuado com sucesso');
          toast.present();
        }, () => {
          console.log('erro ao renderizar o pagamento do paypal');
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Kilomat, but I do not understand how to use your code in my project. I read in the documentation, but every time I add the code, it looks like an error. 
Could you give me a demonstration?
My code is the same in documentation but I do not know how to use it

Comment: It worked, but I have a question: I am receiving a code like: PAY-72J79963NM5333513WLQVCVNHOW but when I check in the Paypal Developer transaction history, my Transaction ID looks like: 3CC23774TG6379823

Comment: Because it is different. PAY-xxxxxx is the id for the payment and 3CCxxxxxxxx is for the transaction. You can have id transaction in the first time. because he bought the order and you have the payment id when he paid

Comment: Thanks for answering me. What do you tell me to do? I need to confirm this transaction with a QR Code, but since they are different, I am confused about what I can do.

Comment: @Kilomat I tried your code but console.log('erro ao renderizar o pagamento do paypal'); is executed always. Please help me with this.